# Compute percentage weights on rows when one column is not numeric

Tags: r, rows, frequency, percentage

I have this data called out:

```
 Dates      Consumer    Staples Energy Financials Health Care
```

1  12/31/99          0         0      0          0          0 
2  03/31/00          0         0      0          0          0 
3  06/30/00          0         0      0          0          0
4  09/30/00          0         0      0          0          0 
5  12/31/00          0         0      0          0          0
6  03/31/01         1000       0      0         50          0
7  06/30/01          0         0      0          0          0

I would like to compute the weights for each category on each row
but need to avoid summing the first column which is a date
Weights <- round(out[2:6]/rowSums(out[2:6])*100, 2)

1/ Is there a way to keep the dates in the first column, and compute
the weights of the next 5 columns in the same data set

2/ When a date has only 0 data, how to avoid the NAs?

Thank you for you help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
outN <- out[,-1]
rownames(outN) <- out[,1]
Cap_Weights <- round(outN/rowSums(outN)*100, 2)

Cap_Weights[is.na(Cap_Weights)] <- 0
```